# meanings of 就 inside 学校内就有银行，很方便

Tags: meaning, usage

> 学校内就有银行，很方便

As I remove 就 from above, then the corresponding translation could be *The school has a bank within its premise and it is very convenient.*

I guess that "already" can be used to translate 就 of the original sentence but I can't be confident about it .

I want to know why 就 is used inside the original sentence.

Comment: I think that I need some much more time to comprehend 就。For now, I can't fully understand the posts below X0 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel this 就 would ordinarily be interpreted as for emphasis.  Maybe two friends were having a conversation:

> 甲：下学了，要陪我去银行吗？
> 乙：学校内就有银行，很方便。

甲 makes it sound like going to the bank is a lot of effort, and would like to go with someone.  In turn, 乙 is highlighting (using 就) that there's a bank on campus; it's not a big deal.  Perhaps 乙 is a little puzzled that 甲 doesn't seem aware of the bank on campus.

However, I recall chatting with a Chinese lady who said 就 a lot.  If she said the quoted sentence, the 就 wouldn't mean anything---she just likes saying 就.

Answer (score 3):

学校内**就**有银行，很方便。

In this sentence, **就** means "indeed", "just", or "in fact".

(1) There is a bank **just** inside the campus.

(2) **Indeed**, the bank on our campus is very convenient.

(3) **In fact**, the bank is not far. It is on our campus.

Comment: "In fact" or "happen to" fit the context

Answer (score 1):

How do we know the meaning of a word? Words often change their meanings.

Apparently the original meaning of 就 was: move to higher ground:

Compound 就 from building 京 jīng and phonetic hand-injured 尤 yóu.

会意。
Combined ideogram

京尤会意。
jīng  yóu combined ideogram

“京”意为高，
"jīng" meaning high,

“尤”意为特别。
"yóu" meaning unusual, special, very, especially

本义:到高处去住
original meaning: go stay in a high place

You will often find 就有 associated with prepositional phrases, see below, like 丈夫死后, 沿路每500码, 学校内 or directly with time phrases: 一开始, once started.

Space and time, Albert Einstein told us, are not two separate things. **then** is just **there** in time, **there** is just **then** in space.

**丈夫死后**她神志**就**有点不大正常了。
husband die after she mental state then have little not very normal
After her husband died, (then) she became a bit strange.

**沿路每500码** **就**有一个炮位。
along road each 500 yards then that one ge cannon position
Every 500 yards along the road (then) there is an artillery position.

这个计划**一开始** **就**有致命的缺陷。
this ge plan once start then have fatal de flaw
This plan had a fatal flaw (then) from the beginning

**学校内** **就**有银行，很方便
school in then have bank, very convenient
In the school (then/there) is a bank, which is very convenient.

Thus, I would interpret 就 in these phrases as a **then** referring to the prepositional phrase or time phrase.